# How to send E-mail Templates through Mailgun?

Tags: php, email, sendmail, mailgun

I am using **Mailgun** as my e-mail Service provider for sending E-mail to my Colleagues. I have created some attractive E-mail Templates. But, I don't know how to send it through Mailgun. Kindly guide me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simple to do if you're using the PHP library from mailgun, available here: https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php

The below code will send an email to a colleague of yours, you can add as many to fields as you need!
Then simply edit the array 'html' :) and execute the script!

```
# Include the Autoloader (see "Libraries" for install instructions)
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = new Mailgun('key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0l');
$domain = "YOURDomain.mailgun.org";

# Make the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'You@yourdomain.com',
    'to'      => 'your_colleague@someone.com',
    'subject' => 'Hello',
    'html'    => 'some html code <b> goes here </b> and works <span style=\"color:red\">fine</span>'
));
```

Comment: @api-sheriff-orlie How to add custom parameters in these html emails. I want to add one field in the html template and later want to set its value from php. Could you please help me to achieve this .

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do a file read of the template and store it temporarily:

```
$fileloc = fopen("/path/to/email_template.php", 'r');
$fileread = fread($fileloc, filesize("/path/to/email_template.php"));

# Instantiate the client.
$mg = new Mailgun('<your_api_key>');
$domain = "domain.com";

# Make the call to the client.
$mg->sendMessage($domain, array('from'    => 'noreply@domain.com', 
                            'to'      => 'recipient@domain.com', 
                            'subject' => 'Subject', 
                            'html'    => $fileread));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$content = view('email.info-request',
            ['sender_name' => Input::get('sender_name'),
             'sender_email' => Input::get('senderr_email'),
             'sender_subject' => Input::get('sender_subject'),
             'sender_message' => Input::get('sender_message')])->render();

$mg->messages()->send('mydomain.com', [
            'from'    => Input::get('sender_email'),
            'to'      => 'admin@mydomain.com',
            'subject' => 'Information Request',
            'html'    => $content]);
```